# css transition linear property not obeyed

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to do linear transition on height of a box. I wrote the following css to achieve that. But the transition is abrupt. The height is suddenly increasing and then the margins are taking up all the time. Why is this happening? Can someone help me fix it?

```
.resource .resource-item-list .resource-item{
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s linear;
    transition: all 3s linear;
}


.resource .resource-item-list .resource-item.open{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;

}
```

[image]

Comment: please add your html also

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is working, but it jumps from 0 `max-height` to 10000px.

The transition does happen in 3 seconds, but you can only see the first 100-200px out of the 10000 (the container height), which takes about 0.03 seconds out of the 3 seconds you set.

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to have a smooth fixed-time transition with a dynamic height container with CSS only.

Comment: can I do something with JS?

Comment: Got it :) https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp